# How to use slots and patterns to reduce repetitive calculation?

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning, pattern-matching

This is kind of complicated...

How can we make MMa calculate values of a function before doing multiple pattern or slot substitutions?  Answers to similar questions didn't cover the case where the form has to be calculated before substitution.

I need to calculate a family of functionals Q[n] for multiple pdfs f[x].

```
maxt = 10;
Do[integrand[t] = Together[f[x]*D[Log[f[x]], {x, 2*t}]/(2^t)], {t, 1, maxt, 1}];
```

Later, the program receives candidate pdf's and can calculate the Q[n]'s.

```
fSub[expr_] := {f[x] -> expr, Derivative[i_][f][x] -> D[expr, {x, i}]};
Do[Q[t] = NIntegrate[integrand[t] /. fSub[c[x]], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}], {t, 1, maxt, 1}];
```

This works, but it is slow for large t as we'd expect.  But f[x] and its derivatives all appear many times in each integrand[t], for example, integrand[2]:

$$\frac{f(x)^3 f^{(4)}(x)-3 f(x)^2 f''(x)^2-6 f'(x)^4-4 f(x)^2 f^{(3)}(x) f'(x)+12 f(x) f'(x)^2 f''(x)}{f(x)^3} $$

...so I believe my method above is slowing things waaay down by calculating f[x] and its derivs multiple times each for every x.

Is there a way to assure that f[x] and its derivs each get calculated just once for each x, then those values are substituted instead of functions?

BTW, the candidate functions f[x]->c[x] can be any pdf, but they are often Gaussian Mixtures, so here's some example code.

```
gauMix[means_, vars_] := Total[Apply[(1/(Sqrt[2*Pi*#2]*Length[vars]))*E^-(((x - #1)^2)/(2*#2)) &, Transpose[{means, vars}], 1]];
c[x] = gauMix[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 4, 2, 1}];
```

BONUS QUESTION:  Since I am going to solve several integrals Q[t] at a time, is there any way to save the f[x] values and deriv values calculated in one integral and reuse them i the next instead of recalculating?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, you'd better give a concrete example, or it'll be hard to give advice.

Comment: @xzczd  There's an entire concrete example laid out in detail in the question, along with all the sample code to run it.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I should have read more carefully. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't go deep to the possible repetitive calculation of `f[x]` and its derivative (actually I doubt if they are the bottleneck of speed, due to my… intuition), but your code got a 1.25X speed up in my computer with the `Together` in your `integrand[t]` being taken away:

```
gauMix[means_, vars_] := 
  Total[Apply[(1/(Sqrt[2*Pi*#2]*Length[vars]))*
      E^-(((x - #1)^2)/(2*#2)) &, Transpose[{means, vars}], 1]];
c[x] = gauMix[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 4, 2, 1}]

fSub[expr_] := {f[x] -> expr, Derivative[i_][f][x] -> D[expr, {x, i}]};

maxt = 3;

Do[integrand[t] = Together[f[x]*D[Log[f[x]], {x, 2*t}]/(2^t)], {t, 1, maxt, 1}];

Table[Q[t] = 
    NIntegrate[
     integrand[t] /. fSub[c[x]], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}], {t, 1, maxt, 1}] // 
AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {2.584000, {-0.166669, 0.00805105, -0.0068687}}
> ```

```
Do[integrand[t] = f[x]*D[Log@f[x], {x, 2*t}]/(2^t), {t, 1, maxt, 1}];

Table[Q[t] = 
    NIntegrate[
     integrand[t] /. fSub[c[x]], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}], {t, 1, maxt, 1}] // 
AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {2.028000, {-0.166669, 0.00805105, -0.0068687}}
> ```

And can get a **20X** speed up with the option `"SymbolicProcessing" -> False`:

```
Table[Q[t] = 
    NIntegrate[integrand[t] /. fSub[c[x]], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
     Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}], {t, 1, maxt, 1}] // 
AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.109200, {-0.166669, 0.00805105, -0.0068687}}
> ```

Comment: Wow, thanks!  But now that you have fixed THIS bottleneck, I think the repetitive calculation really is the new bottleneck.   :-)

Comment: It actually gets about 30% faster still if I replace the Together with an Expand.  But I wonder if that would still be true if the repetitive calculations were eliminated.

Comment: There is a follow-up question that applies these methods and goes deeper into the topic HERE: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69184/

Comment: @JerryGuern According to my test, `Expand` will speed up the code only if the option `"SymbolicProcessing" -> False` isn't added.